# SkCanvas throws when drawing from a task

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

A call to draw picture from an awaited task, will crash my app.

A regular non awaited call will not crash but will not draw my svg.

```
public static Task DrawSVGOnCanvas(SKCanvas canvas, string assemblyName, string svgFileName, SKRect sizeRect, SKPaint paint)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                Stream stream = await GetImageStream(svgFileName, assemblyName, null);
                if (stream == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                stream.Position = 0;
                SKSvg.SKSvg svg = new SKSvg.SKSvg();
                svg.Load(stream);

                SKMatrix scaleMatrix = GetScaleMatrix(svg.Picture, sizeRect);
                canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture, ref scaleMatrix, paint);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logService.HandleException(ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

I was trying to call this async method so I could get the stream for the svg file without locking the ui thread.

Has anyone encountered this, or tried to implement something similiar using skiasharp for svg?

**Update 1:**

The stacktrace for the crash:

```
=================================================================
Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x8d04084e):0x8d04083e  10 98 
00 78 00 28 13 d1 15 b0 bd e8 00 0f f0 bd  ...x.(..........
0x8d04084e  d9 f8 00 00 59 46 2a 46 43 46 d0 f8 c4 60 48 46  ....YF*FCF...`HF
0x8d04085e  b0 47 0e 98 00 28 1e bf 10 98 00 78 00 28 eb d0  .G...(.....x.(..
0x8d04086e  8a f0 cf fb 03 68 10 ae 46 ce 5b 69 13 9d cd e9  .....h..F.[i....

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at SkiaSharp.SkiaApi:sk_canvas_draw_picture <0x00043>
      at SkiaSharp.SKCanvas:DrawPicture <0x001fb>
      at <>c__DisplayClass27_1:<DrawSVGOnCanvas>b__1 <0x000f3>
      at RunnableImplementor:Run <0x000c3>
      at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker:n_Run <0x000bf>
      at Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter:28 <0x000eb>
      at Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter:28 <0x000db>
=================================================================
06-08 16:54:05.532 F/libc    ( 8842): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 8842 (UI)
```

If I am trying to await the call instead of letting it run unawaited I get the following:

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x8d65084e):
0x8d65083e  
10 
98 
00 
78 
00 28 13 d1 
15 b0 bd e8 00 0f f0 bd  ...x.(........
..
0x8d65084e  d9 f8 00 00 59 46 2a 46 43 46 d0 f8 c4 60 48 
46  ..
.
.YF*FCF...`HF
0x8d65085e  b0 47 0e 98 00 28 1e bf 10 98 00 78 00 28 eb 
d0  .G..
.(.....
x.(..
0x8d65086e  8a f0 cf fb 03 68 10 ae 46 ce 5b 
69 13 9d cd e9  .....h..F.[i..
..

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at SkiaSharp.SkiaApi:sk_canvas_draw_picture <0x00043>
      at SkiaSharp.SKCanvas:DrawPicture <0x001fb>
      at <<DrawSVGOnCanvas>b__0>d:MoveNext <0x00823>
      at MoveNextRunner:InvokeMoveNext <0x000d7>
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal <0x0040b>
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run <0x00073>
      at MoveNextRunner:Run <0x0018f>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation:RunOrScheduleAction <0x00183>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishContinuations <0x0032b>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishStageThree <0x00153>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetResult <0x0020f>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1:TrySetFromTask <0x00553>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1:InvokeCore <0x000db>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.UnwrapPromise`1:Invoke <0x000e3>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishContinuations <0x004c7>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishStageThree <0x00153>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetResult <0x0020f>
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1:SetResult <0x00223>
      at <<GetImageStream>b__0>d:MoveNext <0x01637>
      at MoveNextRunner:InvokeMoveNext <0x000d7>
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal <0x0040b>
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run <0x00073>
      at MoveNextRunner:Run <0x0018f>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation:RunOrScheduleAction <0x00183>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishContinuations <0x0032b>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishStageThree <0x00153>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1:TrySetResult <0x0020f>
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1:SetResult <0x00223>
      at <GetObject>d__17`1:MoveNext <0x0077b>
      at MoveNextRunner:InvokeMoveNext <0x000d7>
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal <0x0040b>
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run <0x00073>
      at MoveNextRunner:Run <0x0018f>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation:RunOrScheduleAction <0x00183>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishContinuations <0x0032b>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishStageThree <0x00153>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:FinishStageTwo <0x003bb>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:Finish <0x001c3>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecuteWithThreadLocal <0x002cb>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:ExecuteEntry <0x001d7>
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task:System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem <0x0005f>
      at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue:Dispatch <0x00507>
      at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback <0x0007f>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_bool <0x000bb>
=================================================================
06-08 16:50:38.262 F/libc    ( 8383): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 8439 (Thread Pool Wor)
```

Comment: What is the exception causing the crash?  Have you tried calling DrawPicture on the UI thread?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but the control will not draw, it will remain blank.
I have added the stacktrace to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a result of drawing to the screen from a view, but in the background?

You cannot draw to the screen from a background task or even any task. The on-screen canvas most often only lives as long as the `PaintSurface` event is executing. This is because the OS is no longer doing the drawing and has moved on.

The paint events are always blocking. If you need to draw in the background, you must create a new surface and draw on that. Then you can draw that surface to the screen when it is done. To do this, trigger a refresh and then draw it.

You ssould never keep references to the surface or canvas that was provided by the view. This may be destroyed and recreated at any time.

Comment: Assuming I called refresh or invalidate again, can I create a surface and provide it to the canvas on the next PaintSurface? Isn't the surface object is the one provided to me by the PaintSurface method?

Comment: You can draw to a _new_ surface at any time. But you can only ever reference the surface from the event args _inside_ the paint method.

Comment: So say I paint to a new surface, how do I provide it back to my control? Since now I will be outside the Draw loop, I mean.

Comment: How are you getting this surface? Are you going to create your own? `SKSurface.Create`? If so, then there is a `DrawSurface` and then you can draw that.